# What are the actual effects of enabling Enhanced Commerce Order?

Tags: order, b2b-commerce

I need to enable B2B Commerce on our UAT sandbox for an upcoming deployment. However, this involves enabling "Enable Enhanced Commerce Order" in "Feature Settings > Sales > Order Settings" which is irreversible.

In the tooltip, it says, "Let Users Enhanced Commerce Order", but what does this mean? Specifically, what does this do to existing Users which are not allowed to access the B2B Commerce?

Is there any specific documentation for this?

I tried looking for some documentation on this, but all I found out are steps on how to enable it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting just changes the fields on the cart / order objects to make them play nice with the rest of the LEX product. It is for overall compatibility with CPQ billing (For example without "Enable Enhanced Commerce Orders" and "Enable Optional Price Books for Orders" enabled, the checkout template flows are not available to the admin to edit.

FWIW, Salesforce Order Management also needs the Enhanced Commerce Orders (https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/226/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_order_management_implementation_guide.pdf - page 9)

I must say I couldn't find much documentation around this. I don't see this documented anywhere except in the Lightning Setup guide which states "Turn this on" and then a warning message that says it cannot be undone.

Comment: thanks for the answer. we already went ahead and enabled the enhanced commerce orders. your reply was very helpful. Thanks.